# setValue() simultaneously creating and deleting value

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

We currently have a button that when pressed the first time adds a node as follows /Users/UID/Interests/childByAutoID/"value" and when pressed again deletes the value at the node. The first time the button is clicked the value is added to the node and the value is deleted upon the second click however the third click results in a simultaneous creation and deletion of the value in the database. I cannot seem to understand if this is an issue on my end or with firebase. I have referenced my code below:

```
if(clickedArr[indexPath.row] == false){
            cell.interestsImage.image = selImageArr[indexPath.row]
            ref.child("Users").child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).child("Interests").childByAutoId().setValue(titleArr[indexPath.row])
            clickedArr[indexPath.row] = true
        }
        else{
            ref.child("Users").child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).child("Interests").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
                if(snapshot.value as? String == self.titleArr[indexPath.row]){
                    self.ref.child("Users").child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).child("Interests").child(snapshot.key).removeValue()
                }
            })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you have to fix is you implement the listener for any child added to the node in interest when the button is clicked the second time. what the listener does is when it is added, it deletes it. the listener doesn't go away unless you remove them like notification observers.

if your node only contains one value at a time, you can just fix it by changing child added to just value.

Comment: Thank you so much! I removed the observer and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

When you click the node the first time, you toggle `clickedArr[indexPath.row]` to `true`. But when you click it the second time, you don't toggle it to `false`. You need to do that.